# How to add Analytics pageview tracking in jQuery submit code?

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-analytics

I would like to add the `ga('send', 'pageview', '/contact-successform');` code for the analytics in my contact form but this is the first time I am implementing this. This is the line of code they sent me to add in my code.

I am posting below the current codes of the analytics, jQuery and the form of my page to help you understand and provide me with the solution on where to add this?

Thank you very much for your help.

**Analytics code**

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXX', 'XXX');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**jQuery code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").submit(function() { return false; });
    $("#apostoli").on("click", function(){
            $("#apostoli").replaceWith("<div id='apostoli'><em>please wait</em></div>");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage-contact.php',
                data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#apostoli").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("thank you");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 3000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
```

**HTML form**

```
<form id="contactform" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
   <input type="email"  class="emailaddr" id="emailaddr" name="email">
   <button id="apostoli" class="button" >contact</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://www.aljtmedia.com/blog/tracking-asynchronousajax-website-events-with-google-universal-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Just put it after the setTimeout

```
setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 3000);
ga('send', 'pageview', '/contact-successform');
```